# Dynamically change images directory based on language in PHP?

Tags: php, dynamic, directory, multilingual

I'm working on making a skeleton from which to build small to medium-sized sites in multiple languages. I'm using the method from this tutorial:

http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html

I know it's from 2009 but I like how they did it, and it will be the easiest to understand for my coworkers, especially since I've commented the bejeezus out of the files myself.

This is a good solution for replacing relevant text in the site. The problem I'm facing now stems from the fact that not all the words on any given site are necessarily text. There are plenty of images, navigation buttons, and so on that would need to be replaced as well.

My thought is to go into common.php (as described in the tutorial) and add a conditional that would change the image directory (img/ or image/) as well. For example, if my file structure looked like this:

> www
>
> > index.php
> >     common.php
> >     /img
> >     /jp
> >
> > > lang.jp.php
> > >       /img

If the user selects Japanese as their language and the script runs to get all the text from lang.jp.php, I would want to be using the images in the /img directory within /jp as well.

So my question is, how would I change the src to the proper /img directory for each image tag within the html? Is it possible to use a php switch and set the src to a variable and just call that variable before stating the image name, like `<img src="<?php echo($imgsrc);?>/image.jpg" />`, and assign the path dynamically to $imgsrc? If so, what's the best way to set that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OpenCode had the right idea, but it might be easier to, instead, keep using the img folder you have and make a new folder within it for each language.

```
/img
    /jp
    /en
    /es
        /image.jpg
```

Then use:

```
<img src="/img/<?php echo $lang; ?>/image.jpg" />
```

This way your webroot won't become too messy should you decide to add more languages later on.

Comment: That's a good idea too but the problem is in lang.en/jp.php, it sets $lang as an array. So after the script runs and the page is loaded, I lose the variable. I'm trying to figure out a way to create a separate one with the original $lang value before it gets passed to the language file and turned into an array... not quite sure yet.

Comment: The language is being set as a cookie, so in the file where you add the <img> tag to the page you can do a check for $_COOKIE['lang'] or $_SESSION['lang'] and it should be accessible from there.  Something like:  $lang = (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : ((isset($_SESSION['lang'])) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'en');

Comment: Wait, I see that that _is_ the file in which you need $lang to get the images. So just use a different variable for your images or add another index to the $lang array like $lang['LANGUAGE'] = (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : ((isset($_SESSION['lang'])) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'en'); and then for your images do this: <img src="/img/<?php echo $lang['LANGUAGE']; ?>/image.jpg" />

Comment: Oh wow that was so simple! I will have to brush up on isSet some more because that was pretty slick. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You bet! Glad I could be of service. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The $lang variable holds the short-language-code (language name)

If you have "jp" directory and "img" directory inside "jp" directory then you can do the following too.

```
<img src="<?php echo $lang; ?>/img/image.jpg" />
```

so that it becomes

```
<img src="jp/img/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! However I ran into a problem as I describe in a response to mmmshuddup's comment. After $lang is passed to the language file, the value is reset as an array, so I lose "en" or "jp". The answer is so close I can taste it!

Comment: read about PHP sessions and start tasting your tasty answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but the tutorial you're relying on is just the top of the iceberg.

If you want to make something that is 100% open, easy and fast, do like me (cheekyness taken apart):

1 - make **very** simple languages file, like "ini" files containing only associations, e.g.:

```
text1 = my text
text2 = my text2
text3 = my text3
email_customer = Dear customer
...
```

This way you will be able to translate it very easily.

2 - Then make a "php" cache file that creates a "class" file you'll include.
3 - Make a translator "php" class file that will include translation stuff. In it you may write code like that:

```
if language file more recent than cache file
  => create cache file
...
code to generate "language cache file"
...
include "language cache file"
...
```

3 - Base your language file on the host: use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Here's how I do:

```
- if it's "fr.mysite.com" => it's french language
- if it's "es.mysite.com" => it's spanish language
- ... and so on ...
- if it's "www.mysite.com" => it's default language (your choice)
```

The #1 step is **very** important because you'll gain a lot of time by just sending appropriate files to the translators. No headaches anymore. You'll spend 2-3 days to write it, you'll gain 4-5 days for each new language.

And for the final (and hardest) problem: (FYI it's the 4th time I rewrite my whole framework to include those things, and what I'm explaining here represents many months of developpement even though it seems simple): multilangage files.
Here's how is my directory:

```
templates/
|-- common
|   |-- css
|   |-- htm
|   |   `-- intranet
|   |-- img
|   |-- js
|   |   `-- openid
|   |-- pdf
|   `-- txt
|-- fr
|   |-- css
|   |-- htm
|   |-- img
|   |-- js
|   |-- pdf
|   `-- txt
`-- us
    |-- css
    |-- htm
    |-- img
    |-- js
    |-- pdf
    `-- txt
```

And in your "translator class file" code do something like:

```
...
include "language cache file"
...
**after the include**
...
function get_expanded_path_file() {
  if file exists in language template directory
    return full "language" path + filename
  if file exists in "common" template directory
    return full "common" path + filename

  return "/" filename
}
...
```

Now I hope you get the whole idea. If you want to see real action of such a framework take a look at my latest website (remove my link if you think it's spam or whatever): [mysite](http://groupesynergies.com/)
If you use my advice wisely with something like Smarty, you may end up like me: just doing Php base file, and let everything to translators, and to the webdesigner. FYI this website took me two weeks to develop, 1 day to translate in French and Spanish, and... 3 weeks to agree with the webdesign (lol (or sarcasm who knows))!!!

Hope this helps

Comment: Olivier, this looks very promising. I'm happy with the way I've got going on now, but I was wondering if there was a way to clean up the tags for each section of the translation even more. I'm afraid, though, that I'm still in the beginning stages of my PHP education, so I'm not too certain how to go about executing your method.

I'm more than happy to study up at the PHP manual, but would you kindly tell me what functions I should know to accomplish this?

Comment: Base your language file on the host: use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and, of course, string parsing functions: `mb_strpos()` and all that "thing" around. I'm sorry but if you just begin with Php, try to develop very simple classes (http://php.net/class), then try to look how to read files/strings (http://php.net/fopen) and then come back to my answer in 3 or 4 weeks, I'm pretty sure you'll understand what I mean. Hope this helps and good luck with Php!

Comment: Okay, I'll study more and give it a try. Thank you very much for your help!